# PHP imgefilter parameter value IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH question

Tags: php

I was wondering what does the following sentence mean in laymens terms about the value of the IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH parameter value.

`At about 10, the picture is almost normal, because the original pixel values are given more weight than the combined sum of its neighbors.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool imagefilter ( resource image, int filtertype [, int arg1 [, int arg2 [, int arg3]]] )
```

> IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH: Makes the image
>   smoother. Use arg1 to set the level of
>   smoothness.

See the difference in live action 
http://www.css.kiev.ua/gd-filtry/

Comment: yeah I know that but what does this sentence `because the original pixel values are given more weight than the combined sum of its neighbors.`

Comment: there is no limit but i think its like adding smoothness add more pixel color , which in turn add weight to file as more information is added to file.